# Openssl how to find out what the bit size of the public key in an X509 certificate is

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, rsa, x509

If I have an `X509*` that openssl has provided me, what's the best way to figure out the bit-ness of the RSA public key in the certificate? I can't quite figure this out. I'm pretty sure that if I'm in the SSL certificate verification callback, I can get the X509 ptr with

```
X509 * cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(the_x509_store_ctx);
```

and I would surmise I get the public key like this

```
EVP_PKEY *public_key = X509_get_pubkey(cert);
```

and then I need to check whether it's RSA, presumably?

```
if (public_key && (EVP_PKEY_RSA == public_key->type))
```

and once I know that I got a public key back and that it's RSA, I'd like to do this:

```
int key_length = BN_num_bits(public_key->pkey.rsa->n);
```

but I've found that while this works quite nicely on openssl 0.9.8, on 1.0.1h it segfaults on Windows. The BIGNUM 'n' doesn't seem to be valid - the data ptr in it has a garbage pointer.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Just an idea: could you use `EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA` and then `RSA_size`? You may also want to check if `RSA_free` is required. You could also try and use the OpensSL mailing list - could be a bug...

Comment: Perhaps a copy of the failing code would be nice.... you say what you pretend to do, but not what you are actually doing.

Comment: @owlstead: It looks like that's the right way of doing this. Post as an answer and I'll mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already suggested, to get the RSA modulus size in bytes (so not "bit size"...) use:

```
EVP_PKEY * public_key = X509_get_pubkey(cert);
RSA *rsa_key = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(public_key);
int key_length = RSA_size(rsa_key);
...
RSA_free(rsa_key);
```

Comment: Don't forget to free the ```RSA*``` by callint ```RSA_free``` !

Comment: Also don't forget to add `EVP_PKEY_free( public_key );` to release the reference count on the public key.

Comment: Or use `X509_get0_pubkey()` and `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA()` to avoid having to free anything.